# Method calling null and boolean expression must not be null

Tags: flutter, methods, error-handling

I am working to avoid a  call null on Method when new user register to the app and the favorites are not yet setup.

I placed a condition in both method to retrieve Favorites in order to avoid method calling null.

Now I have an other error message mentioning boolean expression must not be null. i can not figure how to fix avoiding these error message.

Note that is normal that user has no data yet as he just registered.

```
Future<List<dynamic>> getFavorites() async {
   List<dynamic> favorites = await _getFavorites();
   // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
   List<String> favorites_documentid = [];
   
   favorites.forEach((reference) { 
     favorites_documentid.add(reference.documentID); 
     }
     );if (favorites_documentid = null)
     return getFavorites();
 }

 Future<List<dynamic>> _getFavorites() async {  // TODO: Use class-wide list that updates only when a a favorite is added or removed. Even listen to a snapshot for this, if there are lots of favorites.
   DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
       .collection('Users').document(_user.uid).get();
       if (snapshot.data['favorites'] != null) {
   return snapshot.data['favorites'];
// DocumentReference
 } else getFavorites();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe error in this line

```
if (favorites_documentid = null)
```

It should be

```
if (favorites_documentid == null)
```

But it will not help because favorites_documentid never will be null because it initialized before as empty List but not null

```
List<String> favorites_documentid = [];
```

You can check if this list is empty

```
if (favorites_documentid.isEmpty) { ... }
```

And finally seems you have infinite loop when user has no data because from getFavorites() is called _getFavorites()

```
List<dynamic> favorites = await _getFavorites();
```

and if data is null from _getFavorites() is called getFavorites() and so on.

Same in getFavorites();

```
getFavorites() {
   ...
   return getFavorites();
}
```

If I proper understood you. You need to retrieve list of favorites ids.

```
Future<List<String>> getFavoritesIds() async {
  final List<dynamic> favorites = await _getFavorites();
  return favorites.map((reference) => reference.documentID);
}

Future<List<dynamic>> _getFavorites() async {
  final DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('Users').document(_user.uid).get();
  return snapshot?.data['favorites'] ?? []; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful, how would you modify to avoid any null return to Method?

Comment: @JL Edited answer